# Reading files from multiple directions

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make a script that reads .sql files from multiple directories in a certain folder, and then to execute them into the database.

How would I make my code below able to read multiple folders. [These folders will be added/removed in future so I need it to just automatic find any folder without any partciular names.

So for example I have a folder called "mysqls" and inside that folder I have other folders such as 'text1', 'test2'. Test1 and test2 have different .sql files in that I want to be excuted.

```
<?php
$dirf    = 'mysqls';
$dir = scandir($dirf);

unset($dir['0']);
unset($dir['1']);

foreach($dir as $file) {


       $sql = file_get_contents($dirf . '/'. $file);
       $qr = $dbh->exec($sql);
}

?>
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to use SPL's recursive directory iterators

Comment: ? Could you explain that, please.

Comment: What exactly is not working in the provided code?

Comment: @cen The above code is working. Although I am wondering how I would make it to load multiple directories..

Comment: So instead of opening and executing one file at a time you want to open and execute multiple of them? Pretty sure you'll have to make use of multithreading for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('mysqls');

// Filter out "dot" folders
$filter = new DirnameFilter($directory, '/^(?!\.)/');

// Filter sql files 
$filter = new FilenameFilter($filter, '/(?:sql)$/i');

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($filter) as $file) {
    $sql = file_get_contents($file);
    $qr = $dbh->exec($sql);
}


abstract class FilesystemRegexFilter extends RecursiveRegexIterator {
    protected $regex;
    public function __construct(RecursiveIterator $it, $regex) {
        $this->regex = $regex;
        parent::__construct($it, $regex);
    }
}

class FilenameFilter extends FilesystemRegexFilter {
    // Filter files against the regex
    public function accept() {
        return ( ! $this->isFile() || preg_match($this->regex, $this->getFilename()));
    }
}

class DirnameFilter extends FilesystemRegexFilter {
    // Filter directories against the regex
    public function accept() {
        return ( ! $this->isDir() || preg_match($this->regex, $this->getFilename()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this using [RecursiveIteratorIterator()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)

```
<?php 
function scan_for_sql_files($path){
    $itdir = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
    \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD);
    $files = array();
    foreach ($itdir as $path=>$dir){
        if ($dir->isFile()){
            $ext = substr(strtolower($path), -3);
            if($ext == 'sql'){
                $files[] = array('path' => $path);
            }
        }
    }
    return $files;
}

//get files
$files = scan_for_sql_files('mysqls');
//Do sql
foreach($files as $file){
    $sql = file_get_contents($file['path']);
    $qr = $dbh->exec($sql);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('mysqls');
foreach($iterator as $fileinfo){
    if('sql' == $fileinfo->getExtension()){
        $sql = file_get_contents($fileinfo->getPathname());
        $qr = $dbh->exec($sql);
    }
}
```